# i am trying to covert time zone utc to asia/calcutta it show error ORA-01849 hour must between 1 and 12

Tags: plsql

```
create or replace procedure conv_date_1 is
v_date TIMESTAMP  ;
begin
select to_char(from_tz(TO_TIMESTAMP(to_char(SYSDATE,'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'), 'mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'),'UTC')  
at time zone 'Asia/Calcutta','mm-dd-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') into v_date from dual;
dbms_output.put_line('Time is '|| v_date);
end;
```

Comment: it is showing error ORA-01849 Hour must between 1 and 12

Comment: Still its shows same error

Answer (score 0):

this variable v_date is of type timestamp, as the query starts with to_char the variable should be of type varchar2 for example.